# Query items based on size

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

From two table: Item & Box, I want to determine each item in Item table belong to Box_ID in Box table based on height and width.

1. If height and width of item which greate than height & width of box then this item belong to that box_id.
   Example: `I1  4 1 B1 Box 1`
2. Each item is only belong to a box_id.

How to query in sql to return as the below result table?

[image]

Comment: Why do all items have the same id?

Comment: @FuzzyTree: Sorry, this is my mistake. I've corrected.

Comment: how item1 4 : 1 fits b1 1:1

Comment: @Azar: height & width of item 1 greater than height & width of box b1, so item1 belong to box b1.

Comment: Hi ThiLK Can u check the query below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhh finally i have done it check and let me know

```
Select M.*,Box_id,Box_name
from 
(
Select max(B.height) Box_Height ,max(B.width)  Box_Width,M.height ,M.width  
from Item M join Box b on M.Height>=B.Height and M.Width>=B.Width 
group by M.height,M.width

) t
join Item M on  M.Height = t.height and M.width  = t.width
join Box b on   B.Height = t.Box_height and B.width  = t.Box_width
```

Comment: Excellent! I'm very admirable you. Thanks so much!